# Separate unit tests and integration tests with Hardhat and NPM

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, npm-scripts, hardhat

I am trying to setup in my package.json two commands for starting my unit tests and integration tests, but I am having difficulties in specifying a testset (location) for these two types of testing.

In my package.json in scripts section I have created two commands for unit tests and integration tests:

…

```
….
“unit”: “hardhat test test/unit/**/*.test.ts”,
 “integration”: “hardhat test test/integration/**/*.inttest.ts”
….
```

But hardhat test task does not seem to handle the wildcard specification well. It only executes test files which are directly within the directory integration (for integration test case). It is not (recursively) executing test files in subfolders (descendants) of the integration directory.

So, I suspect that this limitation is in the implementation of the test task of Hardhat.
Does any one knows how to specify a command which executes all test files in all descendant folders of unit directory or integration directory?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but,

use `grep` command to test specific tests with Hardhat.

```
hardhat test --grep 'MySmartContract unit test'
```

with your tests containing the `MySmartContract unit test` keywords somewhere in your `describe()` or `it()` descriptions:

```js
describe('MySmartContract unit test', () => {
    it('should do something', () => {})
})
```